# Typo3 Update to CMS 7 -> Problems with ObjectRenderer

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.x

I've updated to CMS 7 and now I've some problems with the ObjectRenderer.
For the TS CONTENT and RECORDS Objects, it does not render correctly and returns always just an empty string. The other TS Objects are working well (TEXT, IMAGE, LINK). 
Therefore I'm asking the question, if the behaviour of the cObjectRendererClass has changed or not?
I've done a lot of research and other people use the cObjectRendererClass in the same way as I am... Here is my code snippet for the ViewHelper, that renders this elements....

```
<?php

namespace TYPO3\Bh\ViewHelpers;

/**
 * @package bh
 * @author Michael Rainer
 * @description Renders a Bakehouse-Content-Object
 *
 */
class CObjectViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {



    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\Bh\Domain\Model\Content $content
     */
    public function render(\TYPO3\Bh\Domain\Model\Content $content) {
        $cObjRenderer = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance("TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer");
        $conf = array( // config
            'tables' => 'tt_content',
            'source' => $content->getUid(),
            'dontCheckPid' => 1
        );

        return $cObjRenderer->render( $cObjRenderer->getContentObject('RECORDS'), $conf );

    }

}

?>
```

Thank you in advance for your helpful responses :).

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I finally got it! To be honest the guy next to me found it.

You have to include "CSS Styled Content" in your Root-Template. 
You may ask why you have to do that? I can't give you an answer. I don't know, probably no one knows. Just do it and it works like a charm.

Lucky me. I don't have to go back to Joomla.